# Value stored "Bool" is never read while analyze app

Tags: ios, xcode

How can i fix this kind of problems 
here is some code

```
BOOL missed = NO;
if (elem.lastCall.lastMissedEvent) {
    if ([elem.status intValue] == 3 && [elem.timeStamp compare:elem.lastCall.lastMissedEvent] != NSOrderedAscending) {
        missed = YES;
    }
}

SCBubbleViewOut *bubble = nil;
if ([cell.bubbleView isKindOfClass:[SCBubbleViewOut class]]) {
    bubble = (SCBubbleViewOut *) cell.bubbleView;
}
```

or here is some more code snipet

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *userid = [members objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    BOOL itsMe = NO;

    if ([userid isEqualToString:[SCUserProfile currentUser].userid]) {
        itsMe = YES;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SCUserProfileControllerSegue" sender:self];
    }
    else
    {
          [self showFriendDetailForUserid:userid];
    }
}
```

from these cases i get

```
Value stored to "BOOL" is never read;
BOOL = itsMe , missed and bubble.
```

Any help is highly appreciated
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What are you asking? Please clean up your question, it's unclear.

Comment: Do you problems understanding the analyzer warning? "value stored is **never read**" sounds pretty clear to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are storing some value into a variable "missed", and you are never using the value stored. So the compiler is wondering why you are doing this, because it is pointless, and the compiler assumes that maybe you wanted to do something else.

If you stored the variable for example so that you can view it in the debugger, add a line

```
(void) missed;
```

That tells the compiler "yes, I know I store a value and I'm not using it, leave me alone". On the other hand, if that's not the case then you need to figure out what you actually wanted to do. The compiler doesn't know, and we don't know. The compiler just says "this doesn't look right", and I can only agree with it.